# Como não permitir indexação por máquinas de busca?

Tags: google, algoritmo-de-busca, web-crawler

Esse dias coloquei o meu domínio no *Google* e ele buscou meu *Web Site* e meu *Sistema*.

Gostaria que meu ***Sistema*** fosse escondido do *Google* e de qualquer outra máquina de busca.

- Teria como fazer isso?
- E como tirar indexação já feita pelo *Google*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basta colocar um arquivo chamado [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/) (tem boa documentação neste *site*) na pasta que você não quer que seja indexado.

Alguns buscadores interpretam o que está escrito dentro para saber mais como devem seguir seu pedido.

O mecanismo de busca não é obrigado a ignorar mas normalmente eles os fazem. Evidentemente se ninguém deveria poder acessar você tem que tomar outras providências limitando o acesso a usuários autenticados, por isso é só uma convenção, é como você ter uma porta sem chave e uma placa dizendo "não entre".

- [Exemplo da própria Google](http://www.google.com/robots.txt).
- [Do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt).

Como é possível perceber dá para declarar quais URLs podem ser acessadas ou não. Pode-se diferenciar dependendo do tipo de cliente (*user-agent*) que está acessando o *site*.

Para proibir em todo o *site*:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Algum tempo após colocar este arquivo os mecanismos que respeitam este arquivo não mais mostrarão o conteúdo em suas páginas. Porém ela [pode ter sido arquivada](https://archive.org/web/web.php) e até onde eu sei sem [ordem judicial](http://tassiaoliveira.jusbrasil.com.br/noticias/119181758/direito-de-ser-esquecido) não é possível que seja retirado.

[Artigo na Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso depende depende do `robots.txt` em si ou dependente do mecanismo de pesquisa "saber lê-lo"?

Comment: É o mecanismo. Ele faz o que ele quiser. Como eu disse na resposta não há nada que impeça qualquer acesso ao conteúdo que não esteja protegido por alguma forma de autenticação.

Comment: @bigown Você acha que mesmo eu colocando o robots o Google e outras maquinas por terem arquivado meu sistema não deiram de desindexá-la?
Encontrei esse gerador de robots. Devo confiar?
http://www.marketingdebusca.com.br/robots-txt/

Comment: @Marconi não posso aconselhar o que eu não conheço mas acho que sim. Veja o conteúdo gerado se é parecido com os exemplos que eu mostrei. Sobre o arquivamento acho que só experimentando. Mas lembre-se que você não estará impedindo nenhum acesso apenas evitará que eles sejam indexados.

Comment: @bigown Sei sim bigown, só quero que o Google a esconda.
Não é intenção impedir acesso mesmo não.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar um arquivo [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) na raiz do seu diretório web com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Lembrando que o robots.txt é somente uma *dica* para que o crawler não indexe aquela página. Os principais motores de busca respeitam o que está indicado no arquivo, mas isso não quer dizer que o conteúdo vai estar invisível ou inacessível.

Através do [Google Webmasters](http://www.google.com.br/webmasters/) você pode [remover seu site dos resultados de busca](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=pt-BR) do Google.

Comment: @Marconi Sem problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque no head

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve configurar o comando `disallow` no arquivo **robots.txt** do seu site.

http://www.seomarketing.com.br/robots.txt.php