# Impedir indexação do Google em pasta específica

Tags: google

Tenho um domínio com um site desenvolvido em Wordpress. No servidor criei uma pasta chamada /chat, não quero que o Google indexe essa pasta. O que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o `Google`, pode utilizar:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

[Fonte](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=pt-BR)

Para a pasta toda como mencionado nessas [respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51399/como-n%C3%A3o-permitir-indexa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-por-m%C3%A1quinas-de-busca):

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /chat
```

Pode testar seu arquivo `robots.txt`

[robots.txt Tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598)

Se estiver usando `Apache`:

```
<Directory /var/www/chat>
    #O sinal "-" representa "no"
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```